# A very strange C++ behavior

Tags: c++, struct, visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors

While I was trying to make my DX11 engine, I had a very strange problem. I couln't find what was wrong. So, I decided to make some simpler code and try to get the same error. This:

Source.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"

using namespace std;

struct1 g_struct1(12);
struct2 g_struct2(&g_struct1);

int main()
{
    cout << "Value of g_struct1.num: " << g_struct1.num << endl;
    cout << "Value of g_struct2.copynum: " << g_struct2.copynum << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Header.h

```
#ifndef _HEADER_H_
#define _HEADER_H_

#include "Header1.h"
#include "Header2.h"

#endif
```

Source1.cpp

```
#include "Header1.h"

struct1::struct1(int number)
{
    num = number;
};
```

Header1.h

```
#ifndef _HEADER1_H_
#define _HEADER1_H_

#include "Header1.h"
#include "Header2.h"

struct struct1
{
    struct1(int number);
    int num;
};

#endif
```

Source2.cpp

```
#include "Header2.h"

struct2::struct2(struct1 *par1)
{
    copynum = par1->num;
};
```

Header2.h

```
#ifndef _HEADER2_H_
#define _HEADER2_H_

#include "Header1.h"
#include "Header2.h"

struct struct2
{
    struct2(struct1 *par1);
    int copynum;
};

#endif
```

Error

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Source.cpp
1>c:\users\<My Username>\desktop\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\header2.h(10): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'struct1'
1>c:\users\<My Username>\desktop\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\source.cpp(8): error C2664: 'struct2::struct2(const struct2 &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'struct1 *' to 'const struct2 &'
1>          Reason: cannot convert from 'struct1 *' to 'const struct2'
1>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Of course, the second error doesn't matter because the compiler thinks it's a copy constructor.

If I change `struct2::struct2(struct1 *par1)` to `struct2::struct2(void *par1)` and then cast `void *par1` to `struct1*`, it works fine.

Well, if you made it this far, thanks. And sorry for bad English.

Comment: You are including `Header1.h` in `Header1.h`  and `Header2.h` in `Header2.h`. That probably confuses your include guards. You should fix that first.

Comment: What happens when you use struct2(struct struct1 *par1); instead of struct2(struct1 *par1);?

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks for your comment. No, it doen't matter, because without include guards Header1.h includes Header2.h, which includes Header1.h. So they include themselves anyway. That's why I use include guards. Commenting those lines doesn't work.

Comment: @LHLaurini You should fix the includes anyway.

Comment: It is almost certainly a problem with the includes, because this code compiles just fine if pasted together in one file manually. Since include should basically do the same it must be the includes.

Comment: @midor Yes, forgot to say that. When in one file, it works fine too.

Comment: Circular includes and files including themselves is the issue.  Fix that and you'd be fine.  Use forward declarations instead of including where possible.

Comment: @LHLaurini That question title doesn't look really helpful for anyone researching after you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your headers have circular dependencies. They even include themself which is silly. The end result is that neither header gets processed properly.

In `Header1` remove both `#include` lines. In `Header2` remove `#include "Header2.h"`. This should fix the problem.

Comment: Now I got it. `Header1.h` doesn't need `Header2.h`. Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

It does not work because during the definition of struct2 the struct1 is not defined and you are using the non-defined struct poniter in your construction.

Simply fix would be

```
struct struct2
{
    struct2(struct struct1 *par1); // note the struct struct1 *
    int copynum;
};
```

Also you don't have to depend on Header1.h in Header2.h (but you do in Source2.cpp) if you do use this.

Comment: And why isn't `struct1` defined if `Header1.h` is included? Because the includes are messed up.

Comment: @juanchopanza i agree with you, but the Header1 is depend on the Header2, and Header2 is depend on the Header1. What can the user do?

Comment: @BurakTamtürk Add third header

Comment: This is C++, this shouldn't be the best way of fixing it.

Comment: @juanchopanza i mean it can be... and zoska of course it can be, That's why in Qt applications you can define QPushButton* in header file without depending QPushButton.hpp in the code. Unless you define it you just can't use the method this class includes.

Comment: @zoska Right, this is not fix. It just hides a problem.

Comment: @BurakTamtürk that's totally not the case here

Comment: @juanchopanza one can use struct2 in Header1 and struct1 in Header2. I don't understant the downvotes.